# I want to change the default download location of the chain data to an SD card instead of the internal hard drive. How can I go about it?

Tags: go-ethereum

I want to change the default download location of the Geth chain data from the internal hard drive and use an SD card instead. How can I go about it?

OS: Ubuntu 15.10.

The hard drive is kind of small and all the IO operations on the hard drive are distracting. I think it should be possible to make Geth download the chain data to an external location, specifically an external SD card in this case. How can I do it?

Comment: This question will probably be closed [as a duplicate](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) soon. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!